# Возможен ли линейный поиск диаметра графа?

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день! Возможен ли линейный поиск диаметра графа (O(M+E))? Есть алгоритм за O(M*(M+E)) (поиск длиннейшего пути от каждой вершины), но это медленно. Есть ли более быстрый алгоритм? Диаметр графа - это расстояние в ребрах наиболее удаленных друг от друга вершин.

Answer (score 2):

Вольный перевод из [Estimating all pairs shortest paths in restricted graph
families: a unified approach (2005)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.1493&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> В общем случае, чтобы найти кратчайшее
> расстояние между всеми парами вершин в
> графе, требуется `O(M(n)log n)`, где
> `M(n)` время умножения матрицы (с
> маленькими целыми числами) т.е.
> `O(n**2.376)` (алгоритм Копперсмита-Винограда). Для сравнения, простой поиск в ширину ведёт к `Θ(nm)` алгоритму,
> что является `Θ(n**3)` для плотных графов. `n`
> - кол-во вершин, `m` - кол-во рёбер. Оптимальное время `O(n**2)` может быть достигнуто для некоторых типов графов.

т.е. линейных по числу вершин алгоритм (основанный на сравнении путей) невозможен для произвольных графов (note: кол-во рёбер квадратично кол-ву вершин в плотных графах).